# How to display framebuffer with qemu for custom RPi 1B+ kernel?

Tags: pi-b+, qemu, bare-metal, pi-1

I'm working on a little bare-metal project on the RPi 1 B+ and I'm having some trouble with qemu... I succeeded in printing to real screen using the framebuffer (i.e. I hooked a real screen over HDMI to my RPi 1B+ and could see the printed text), but I'm struggling to get this emulated correctly using `qemu`. So far, the workflow has been building the `kernel.elf` file and running it via `qemu` to see if the behaviour is correct.

```
qemu-system-arm -m 512 -M raspi1ap -serial null -serial stdio -kernel path_to/kernel.elf
```

This was useful when only working with uart (I added `-serial null -serial stdio` to redirect UART1 to terminal) but now that everything is set up to work with the GPU and print to real screen over the framebuffer, I wanted to adjust qemu to reflect that as well...

I'm quite confident this should be possible (if you can emulate the entire RPi with qemu, then you should also be able to emulate my small kernel) but I'm having trouble getting this to work... I found some answers in the [RaspberryPi forum](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=333505), i.e. this question but if I'm not misunderstanding, the suggested approach seems to be to use [Ultibo](https://ultibo.org), which I would like to avoid (I'd just like to figure out what the correct arguments to qemu are to get the framebuffer displayed). I also found another from 2012 or so, but this suggested to use Torlus' patches, but these have been integrated into qemu since 2016 or so (I think at least, assuming I'm looking at the right [github page](https://github.com/Torlus/qemu/tree/rpi)...)

Does anybody have a hint how to get this setup correctly to run with qemu? What exactly do I need to add to the command to emulate a real screen? Im running version 7.2 on macOS (qemu installed over brew), but I can of course also build it from source if this should be necessary to get this working.